# What is the point of the "is" syntax when extending elements in web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

In web components, to register an element you simply type:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

To create an element you can do one of these:

```
<x-foo></x-foo>

var xFoo = new XFoo();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);

var xFoo = document.createElement( 'x-foo')
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
```

This is all fine and dandy. The issues start when you are talking about extending existing elements.

```
var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});
```

**Question 1**: Why the duplication? Here, `'button'` should suffice (especially since it's easy enough to work out the element's prototype with `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement(tag));`

**Question 2**: How is that information used *internally*? What happens if you for example have `prototype: Object.create(HTMLFormElement.prototype` and `extends: 'button'` (where what's after `extends` doesn't match the prototype passed)

To create one you can do one of these:

```
<button is="x-foo-button"></button>

var xFooButton = new XFooButton();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);

var xFooButton = document.createElement('button', 'x-foo-button');
document.body.appendChild(xFooButton);
```

**Question 3**: since it's clear that `x-foo-button` extends `button`, why do we have to specify both of them when we use `document.createElement()`? I suspect that's because `document.createElement()` simply creates a tag with syntax `<button is="x-foo-button"></button>`, which brings me to the next question:

**Question 4**: What's the point of the `is` syntax? What is the actual difference between doing this:

```
var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});
```

And this:

```
var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
});
```

Other than 1) The first syntax will need `<button is="x-foo-button"></button>` to create an instance in the document 2) The second syntax can be used on *any* element, not just an extension of the custom ones?

Comment: 4 years later...  As an example: Besides the standard Autonomous Custom Element:  ``<card-t cid='queen-of-cards'></card-t>`` I have also added 52 Elements extending IMG:  ``<img is=queen-of-hearts>`` in https://github.com/card-ts/playingcardts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Answer 1**
The apparent duplication is because your example is very simple. In the real virtual life, you would provide a different prototype to `registerElement`.

Example with a custom button that will display a popup when clicked:

```
//Custom method
function callback ()
{
    console.log( this + " {created}" )
    this.onclick = function ( event )
    {
        alert( this.id + " " + this.value )
    } 
}

//Type Extension
var newProto = Object.create( HTMLButtonElement.prototype )
newProto.createdCallback = callback
var XFooButtonExt = document.registerElement( 'x-foo-button', {
    prototype: newProto,
    extends: 'button'
} )
```

`newProto` is different than `HTMLButtonElement`'s `prototype`.

With the following HTML code:

```
<button is="x-foo-button" id="Hello" value="World"> Hello </button>
```

A click on it will display "Hello World" in a popup.

---

**Answer 2**
The `extends: 'button'` is a semantic  indication that tells the browser that the new prototype provided implements the `HTMLButtonElement` interface. That's why it's easier to start with an object that inherits from `HTMLButtonElement`. Instead you could start with an `HTMLFormElement` prototype but you would have to reimplement all the properties and methods of the `HTMLButtonElement` interface.

If not, the element behaviour will be incorrect. In the above example, if you replace a line by:

```
var newProto = Object.create( HTMLFormElement.prototype )
```

... the click on it will fail because the property `value` is not implemented in a `<form>` element.

The property `id` is always correct because it is provided by the `HTMLElement` interface, implemented by every elements (including `<form>`).

Note that you could add the missing properties, and link them to their attribute in the `attributeChangedCallback` method.

---

**Answer 3** 
You are correct. This maintains backward compatibility with old browsers that will ignore the second argument, still being able to create a *normal* element (a standard `<button>` in your example).

---

**Answer 4**
There are 2 different concepts behind the *Custom Elements* paradigm:

1. **Type Extensions** (*Customized Built-in Elements*) if you want to extend a standard HTML element.
2. **Custom Tag** (*Autonomous Custom Elements*) if you want to define custom elements with new names.

Both are defined with the same method `registerElement`. The `extends`/`is` option permits you to choose one of them.

The `is` syntax works only with *Type Extensions* and is therefore always associated with the `extends` option.

With *Type Extensions*, you keep all the semantics of the element you extend: CSS styles, built-in behaviour (interfaces), accessibility features. Backward compatibility is another benefit of this syntax.

With *Custom Tags*, you loose the semantics and your custom element is expected to implement only the `HTMLElement` interface, with no built-in style or behavior.

**Update**: the next example (for Chrome and Opera) illustrates the difference between *Type Extension* and *Custom Tag*.

```js
//Method
function callback() {
  this.textContent = this //Get the HTML semantics
  this.onclick = function(event) {
    try {
      var output = this.id + " "
      output += this.name        //works only with <button is=...>
    } 
    catch (e) {
      output += "a generic element"
    }
    alert(output)
  }
}

//Type Extension
var newProto = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype)
newProto.createdCallback = callback

var XFooButtonExt = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: newProto,
  extends: 'button'
})

//Custom Tag
var newProto2 = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype)
newProto2.createdCallback = callback

var XFooButtonCust = document.registerElement('x-foo-button-2', {
  prototype: newProto2,
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Custom Elements</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Type Extension</h3>
  <button is="x-foo-button" id="I'm" name="a button">Type Extension</button>
  <h3>Custom Tag</h3>
  <x-foo-button-2 id="I'm" name="a button">Custom Tag</x-foo-button-2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great answer. Two points, both on Answer 4: "With Type Extensions, you keep all the semantics of the element you extend: CSS styles, built-in behaviour (interfaces), accessibility features". Don't you get ALL of those by typing `var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
});` ? If you make a custom tag as specified here, with the right prototype, don't you get to keep the semantics with no built-in style or behavior?

Comment: No, you don't keep the semantics. That means that your browser ignore that you custom tag is derived from a button. A reader for a blind won't detect it as a button. (Of course all the methods and properties inherited form `HTMLButtonElement` prototype will work, although not linked with button's specific attributes: `value`,`name`, etc.)

Comment: Holy golly I didn't know that! So... the browser treats specific elements like `<button>` in specific ways, applying CSSes and specific behaviours? How does that work?

Comment: I suppose it's based on the element name (or interface). That's why it works with Type Extensions that keep the original element names. In my snippet, if you inspect the first button with Dev Tools, you'll see that Chrome applies on it an internal stylesheet named `user agent stylesheet`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this question -- and especially you answer -- are absolutely awesome. The best bounty I ever started!

Comment: You already have 1/4 of the karma points I have. I think this answer alone gave you tons of it! (well deserved :D )