# How to retrieve values of custom DOM properties?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, customization

I am trying to retrieve that value of `amount="y"` for `itemindex="x`" in the following block of HTML,

```
<ul>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="14" amount="500.00">$500</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="15" amount="300.00">$300</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="16" amount="150.00">$150</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="17" amount="75.00">$75</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="18" amount="35.00">$35</li>
 </ul>
```

I am not sure how to go about this with the usual, `document.getElementBy...('').value;`

If anyone has any suggestions that would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `elm.getAttribute(strAttrName)`, or use `document.registerElement` to create custom tags with direct attribute bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `document.querySelector()` , attribute selector `"li span[itemindex='17']"` for example to select element having `itemindex` attribute set to `"17"`; `Element.getAttribute()` , as suggested by @dandavis .

```js
var el = document.querySelector("li span[itemindex='17']");
console.log(el.getAttribute("amount"))
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="14" amount="500.00">$500</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="15" amount="300.00">$300</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="16" amount="150.00">$150</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="17" amount="75.00">$75</li>
 <li><span class="vaTop" itemindex="18" amount="35.00">$35</li>
 </ul>
```

See also

[What is the point of the "is" syntax when extending elements in web components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055503/what-is-the-point-of-the-is-syntax-when-extending-elements-in-web-components/)

[Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)