# Browser custom namespaced element processors

Tags: javascript, html, xml-namespaces

in browser environment, creating an svg element this way
`svg = document.createElement('svg');`
appending it to body and populating with svg elements does not work, because
`svg.namespaceURI === 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'`
but doing this way
`svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')`
it will work.
That's reasonable as that element should be processed in *svg way* and not in *html way*
similarly, creating
`select = document.createElementNS('xxxx','select')`
and appending to body, the element won't show up as a well known `select` dropdown, because the browser is informed that it is not an `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml:select` element but it is an `xxxx:select` instead.
It seemes like node processing are dispatched to different processors depending on the NS(when recognized) of the node itself.
Is it possible to define a custom namespaceURI for a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) in order to let its nodes with that specific nsURI to be processed in a custom fashion, likely through a function ?

Comment: Yes, should be possible. What is expected result ?

Comment: How? I'm not going toward a specific result, i'm evaluating different ways to intercept document processing, and this scenario looks juicy

Comment: One approach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055503/what-is-the-point-of-the-is-syntax-when-extending-elements-in-web-components?s=4|0.0000; see also http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html . Can define _"let the browser dispatch processing to them in some way"_ ? What would "processing" include ?

Comment: yep, this is about custom elements, i  know them, the topic is hot and controversial, with sparse support, but it's not about namespaces

Comment: processor should do kinda things like custom elements, but i'd like it to work in plain xml documents too.. as i told you, i'm scouting for alternative candidates for the job

Comment: _"I'm not going toward a specific result"_ , _"i'm scouting for alternative candidates for the job"_ What is "the job" ? Not certain what requirement is ? Tried defining a custom `dtd` ? , using `xlst` ?

Comment: dtd and xslt is impracticable in browser.. but back to my Q:«custom processors for **custom namespaceURIs**» , you said «Yes, should be possible», how?

Comment: _"but back to my _", you said «Yes, should be possible», how? "_ Define own `dtd` for how to handle document ; elements in document; though not recommended https://www.w3.org/Style/customdtd.en.html. Or , use `document.registerElement` http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/custom-elements/ . Could also use `ProcessingInstruction` , similar to `php` . Requirement of Question not appear clear, here. Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle to demonstrate application ?

Comment: See also http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlname/pi

Comment: nice, thanks! i read some about PI before, but i misunderstood it was only the XML declaration, thanks to your link i see it's some more and it looks another nice candidate for my needs, sure i'll dig into it, anyhow i edited Q, hope it is clearer.

Comment: Expected results still not clear , here. `ProcessingInstruction` can  be used at `html` document as well

Answer (score 1):

Note, not certain what expected result is ? Answer attempts to demonstrate one method of using a `ProcessingInstruction`

```js
// create `ProcessingInstruction`
var p = document.createProcessingInstruction("js", "{\"color\":\"blue\"}");
var div = document.getElementById("process");
document.body.insertBefore(p, div);
// use `ProcessingInstruction`
div.style.color = JSON.parse(div.previousSibling.nodeValue).color;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="process">Process</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I liked the idea of using PIs, despite it's not about namespaces, and i made some tests, well, adding a PI node programmatically as you did is ok, but html parsing does not handle PIs and cast them to comment node. html unsupported is stated in the link you provided too [«It HTML we have no Processing Instructions. »](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlname/pi) .. pity ..

Comment: The `html` document could be parsed for node type 7 or node type 8, the `data` property of those nodes could further be parsed, without creating processing instruction using `js`. Other alternatives could be using `xhtml`and including `xslt` with `stylesheet` or `javascript` external instruction resources or nodes within the document ; could also use `shadowRoot` with `template` and `content` elements to render custom instructions , depending on expected results of application.