# document.registerElement - Why do we need to specify both 'prototype' and 'extends'?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

Consider I want to extend the native `button` element, and create my own `super-button` element. As I know, it must follow the following pattern:

```
var SuperButton = document.registerElement('super-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});
```

It looks strange to me - doesn't the `prototype` and `extends` parameters say the same thing? If I explicitly say that my `super-button` use the `HTMLButtonElement` prototype, why do I also need to specify that it extends the button element? isn't it redundant? For me it looks like exactly the same information.

Comment: No, there can be multiple tags that share the same prototype.

Comment: so the 'extends' part is more about inheriting the element's style and look?

Comment: No, `extends` is about inheriting builtin behaviour (e.g. how it acts in a form) of an element. You'll want to read about the distinction between custom elements and type extensions.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think multiple custom tags can share the same proptoype (`registerElement` won't accept that)

Comment: @Supersharp: I don't know (have not tried), but what I meant is that you cannot infer a tag name from the prototype (chain). If I create a prototype for my custom tag with `Object.create(HTMLQuoteElement.prototype)`, what do you think will it extend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Custom Elements specification](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-type-extension-example):

> In general, the name of the element being extended cannot be determined simply by looking at what element interface it extends, as many elements share the same interface (such as q and blockquote both sharing HTMLQuoteElement).

In other words, while it may be redundant for `<button>` elements, it isn't redundant in general and the spec needs to support the general case.

I would argue that it isn't even redundant for `<button>` though, as there is nothing preventing you from doing:

```
var SuperButton = document.registerElement('super-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'a'
});
```

Comment: ok, so as far as I understand, the 'extends' part is about inheriting the style and inner DOM of an element, while the 'prototype' is about functionality. Am I right?
Otherwise, I don't understand what it means to extend the button's prototype, and also be an 'a' element in the same time. It is quite confusing :-).

Comment: @gipouf you can read this post for further detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055503/what-is-the-point-of-the-is-syntax-when-extending-elements-in-web-components?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Paulpro's answer: the `extends` creates the `is=` syntax. If `q` and `blockquote` both share `HTMLQuoteElement`, and you extend `q`, then you can write `<q is="super-button">` but cannot write `<blockquote is="super-button">`.

Regarding what means to extend an `a` link with another element's `prototype`, this would create a link that does not have the appropriate functions and properties, which is bad:

See: https://jsfiddle.net/3g0pus8r/

```
<a is="anchor-one" href="google.com">1st link</a>
<a is="anchor-two" href="google.com">2nd link</a>

var proto1 = Object.create(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, {
  createdCallback: {
    value: function() { 
    console.log("1st:");
    console.log(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.isPrototypeOf(this));
    console.log(this.hostname);
    console.log(this.toString());
    }
  }
});

var proto2 = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype, {
  createdCallback: {
    value: function() {        
    console.log("\n2nd:");
    console.log(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.isPrototypeOf(this));
    console.log(this.hostname);
    console.log(this.toString());
    }
  }
});

document.registerElement("anchor-one",{prototype:proto1, extends: "a"});
document.registerElement("anchor-two",{prototype:proto2, extends: "a"});
```

The result is:

```
1st:
true
fiddle.jshell.net
https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/google.com

2st:
false
undefined
[object HTMLButtonElement]
```

However, you may still want to:

- Extend `MyOtherAnchor` which in turn extends `HTMLAnchorElement`;
- Extend `HTMLElement` and implement all the anchor interface yourself.
- Create an anchor with a different, non-standard, interface.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, its allows you to distinguish between [*Custom Tags*](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-custom-tag-example) declaration versus [*Type Extensions*](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-type-extension-example) declaration (as suggested by Bergi's second comment), as both share the same method `document.registerElement()`.

**Type Extensions: use `extends`**

```
document.registerElement( "button-v2",  { 
    prototype: Object.create( HTMLButtonElement.prototype ),
    extends: 'button'
} )
```

`<button-v2>` will continue to act as a `<button>` (*ie* keeps its semantics).

**Custom Tags: don't use `extends`**

```
document.registerElement( "not-button",  { 
    prototype: Object.create( HTMLButtonElement.prototype )
} )
```

`<not-button>` inherits from `HTMLButtonElement` interface but lost its semantics (*ie* won't act as a `<button>`)

---

NB: If the only reason was really because you cannot always infer an `<element>` from its prototype chain, an optional parameter would have been proposed to disambiguate such rare cases. Here they have choosen a common, *synthetic* method, which is confusing at first sight you're right!