# Clicking label not focusing custom element (Web Components)

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I’m writing a custom `<select>` element using native DOM (no Polymer).

I’m trying to use my element with a `<label>` element and correctly trigger click events to my element when the `<label>` is clicked, i.e.:

```html
<label>
  My Select:
  <my-select placeholder="Please select one">...</my-select>
</label>
```

or

```html
<label for='mySelect1'>My Select:</label>
<my-select id='mySelect1' placeholder="Please select one">...</my-select>
```

However, this behavior doesn’t seem to work out of the box, even if I add a `tabindex` to make it focusable.

Here’s a stripped down version of the code and a [JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/h56692ee/2) with some basic debugging:

```js
var MySelectOptionProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
document.registerElement('my-select-option', {
  prototype: MySelectOptionProto
});
var MySelectProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

MySelectProto.createdCallback = function() {
  if (!this.getAttribute('tabindex')) {
    this.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
  }
  
  this.placeholder = document.createElement('span');
  this.placeholder.className = 'my-select-placeholder';
  this.appendChild(this.placeholder);

  var selected = this.querySelector('my-select-option[selected]');
  
  this.placeholder.textContent = selected
    ? selected.textContent
    : (this.getAttribute('placeholder') || '');
};
document.registerElement('my-select', {
  prototype: MySelectProto
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) elements can be targeted by [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

So you'll have to manage the focus action by yourself if you want to use a non-standard (*autonomous custom*) element.

Instead you can choose to define a *Customized built-in element* that will extend the `<select>` element, as in the following example:
https://jsfiddle.net/h56692ee/4/

```
 var MySelectProto = Object.create( HTMLSelectElement.prototype )
 //...
 document.registerElement('my-select', { prototype: MySelectProto, extends: "select" } )
```

You'll need to use the `is` attribute notation for HTML:

```
<label>
   My Select:
   <select is="my-select" placeholder="Please select one">
       <option>...</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

**Update** More explanations in these 2 posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34157348/4600982) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37188074/4600982).

Comment: i find having to extend using the `is` keyword quite cumbersome as that means some of my elements will required to be written using a different html structure to others. I opted for wrapping a select element and using it to handle focus. It would have been nice though, to be able to implement said **phrasing content** interface directly

Comment: Thank you for the points. I was like you, then I realized that both custom elements (with and without `is`) are for different purposes, so now I use both depending of my needs. But the standard is not finished, and maybe in the future you'll be able to use the built-in semantic with autonomous custom elements, too. I've updated may answer with links to explanations on the diffenrences between the two syntax.

Answer (score 6):

> But the standard is not finished, and maybe in the future you’ll be able to use the built-in semantic with autonomous custom elements, too.
>
> — [Supersharp, Jul 15, 2016 at 16:05](/q/38320270/4642212#comment64209394_38330549)

We live in the future now.
The standard has significantly changed and we have more capable custom elements now.

---

### Tl;dr:

Labels work iff the constructor associated with your custom element has a `formAssociated` property with the value `true`.

---

When looking at the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for), at first sight, you might conclude that custom elements are not allowed as `<label>` targets.
The docs say:

> Elements that can be associated with a `<label>` element include `<button>`, `<input>` (except for `type="hidden"`), `<meter>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

But custom elements are not mentioned.
You try your luck anyway and try to enter this HTML fragment in an [HTML validator](//validator.nu/#textarea):

```html
<label>Label: <my-custom-element></my-custom-element></label>
```

or:

```html
<label for="my-id">Label: </label><my-custom-element id="my-id"></my-custom-element>
```

and both of these are valid HTML snippets!

However, trying this HTML fragment:

```html
<label for="my-id">Label: </label><span id="my-id"></span>
```

shows this error message:

> Error: The value of the `for` attribute of the `label` element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.

But why is a random `<my-custom-element>` considered a “non-hidden form control”?
In the [validator’s GitHub issues](//github.com/validator/validator/issues?q=%22non-hidden+form+control%22) you then find the already fixed [issue #963](//github.com/validator/validator/issues/963):

> ### `label for` doesn’t allow custom elements as targets
>
> The spec allows form-associated custom elements as `for` targets
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-label-for
>
> This currently triggers an error:
>
> ```html
> <label for="mat-select-0">Select:</label>
> <mat-select role="listbox" id="mat-select-0"></mat-select>
> ```
>
> Easy to check if element name contains a dash.
> Much harder to check that custom element definition includes a `static formAssociated` property returning `true`, since this is likely buried deep in an external framework `.js` file:
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example

There is indeed one peculiar addendum in the [WHATWG specification](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) which enumerates the same “labelable elements” as the documentation ***plus* [form-associated custom elements](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-element)**.
There is an [example](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-accessibility-example) in the specification, and researching this problem today yields this Q&A post in the results as well as blog articles such as [*“More capable form controls”* by Arthur Evans](//web.dev/more-capable-form-controls) ([archived link](//web.archive.org/web/20220823083921/https://web.dev/more-capable-form-controls/)), which show what the solution is.

### The solution to enable `<label>` clicking targeting custom elements: `formAssociated`

All that needs to be done to *enable* the `<label>` action is to add a `formAssociated` property with the value `true` to the constructor of the custom element.

However, the code in the question needs to be ported to the current [Web Components API](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).
The new `formAssociated` property is part of the new ElementInternals API (see [`attachInternals`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/attachInternals)) which is used for richer form element control and accessibility.

Nowadays, custom elements are defined with [`classes`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) and [`customElements.define`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define), and [ShadowRoots](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) are used.
The `static formAssociated = true;` field can then be added to the class which you consider to belong to the “form-associated custom elements”.
Having this property makes your custom element dispatch `click` events when clicking the `<label>`; now we’re getting somewhere!

In order to turn this `click` into a `focus` action, there’s one more thing we need in the [`attachShadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) call: the property `delegatesFocus` set to `true`.

```js
// Rough translation of your original code to modern code, minus the `tabIndex` experimentation.

class MySelectOptionProto extends HTMLElement{}

customElements.define("my-select-option", MySelectOptionProto);

class MySelectProto extends HTMLElement{
  #shadowRoot;
  #internals = this.attachInternals();
  static formAssociated = true;
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.#shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open",
      delegatesFocus: true
    });
    this.#shadowRoot.replaceChildren(Object.assign(document.createElement("span"), {
      classList: "my-select-placeholder"
    }));
    this.#shadowRoot.firstElementChild.textContent = this.querySelector("my-select-option[selected]")?.textContent ?? (this.getAttribute("placeholder") || "");
  }
}

customElements.define("my-select", MySelectProto);
```

```html
<label>My label:
  <my-select placeholder="Hello">
    <my-select-option>Goodbye</my-select-option>
    <my-select-option>world</my-select-option>
  </my-select>
</label>

<label for="my-id">My label:</label>
<my-select id="my-id">
  <my-select-option>Never gonna give you</my-select-option>
  <my-select-option selected>up</my-select-option>
</my-select>
<label for="my-id">My other label</label>
```

`delegatesFocus` will focus the first focusable child of the shadow root, when some non-focusable part of the custom element has been clicked.

If you need more control, you can remove the property, and add an event listener to the custom element instance.
In order to be sure that the click came from the `<label>`, you can check if the event’s `target` is your custom element, i.e. `this`, and that the element at the x and y position on the screen was a `<label>` targeting your custom element.
Fortunately, this can be done quite reliably by passing [`x`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/x) and [`y`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/y) to [`document.elementFromPoint`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint).
Then, simply calling [`focus`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on your desired element will do the job.

The list of labels that target a custom element is another thing that the ElementInternals API provides via the [`labels`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals/labels) property.

```js
class MySelectProto extends HTMLElement{
  // …
  constructor(){
    // …

    this.addEventListener("click", ({ target, x, y }) => {
      const relatedTarget = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
      
      if(target === this && new Set(this.#internals.labels).has(relatedTarget)){
        console.log("Label", relatedTarget, "has been clicked and", this, "can now become focused.");
        // this.focus(); // Or, more likely, some target within `this.#shadowRoot`.
      }
    });
  }
}
```