# How to listen for LightDOM Label "FOR=" events via ShadowDOM Custom Element

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dom-events, shadow-dom, custom-element

***EDIT 1***

@Danny (and everyone)

"Is there a reason your  needs to be independent outside the Component? "

Please let me explain the use-case here. My custom-element ABC-TOGGLE is (wants to be) Label agnostic. Whether or not a LABEL tag is present is completely at the disgression of the LightDOM author/caller of my component. All I want/need to do is acknowledge the runtime environment/ambience and adapt accordingly.

Just as ABC-TOGGLE is agnostic to being part of a HTML FORM, yet will comply with either environment.

IMHO, (nah it's bleeding obvious) a click on a user-supplied LABEL FOR my Web Component MUST generate a click-event on #disTick.

If you are saying this is impossible or the specification rules it out then fine, please post link. Otherwise, what do I listen on?

***END EDIT 1***

How do I get a caller's HTML "Label" surrounding my Custom Element to bubble its "click" events to my shadow root? Is there not something in the shadowRoot that I can listen for Click events for my LightDOM label?

I believe this [clicking labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320270/clicking-label-not-focusing-custom-element-web-components) answer comes close but I am inheriting from HTMLElement.

In the following code I want my ABC-TOGGLE custom element to hear events on label "aLabel".

```
export class ABCToggle extends HTMLElement 
{
    static formAssociated = true;
```

No joy (#toggle is the top level element): -

```
    this.#shadowRoot.host.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("SR click");
    });
        
    this.#shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("SR click");
    });
    this.#toggle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
```

Calling HTML: -

```
    <div id="disableIt">
    <label id="aLabel" for="disTick">Disable Toggle&nbsp;</label>
    <div id="tickContainer">
        <abc-toggle id="disTick" name="disTick" checked="false" tabindex=0 type="tick"></abc-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this guide you in the right direction? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example

Comment: a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @richard Judging by that code I should just be able to say   this.#shadowRoot.host.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
but still no event :-( I couldn't see a code pen (or other) in that link. Do you have one? It's OK I'll cut & paste.

Comment: @richard that example has no shadow DOM. SO I'm guessing Apples vs Oranges

Comment: Is there a reason your ``<label>`` needs to be **independent outside** the Component? That label **disTick** can be anywhere in the document, including hidden in other shadowRoots. So you have to set some boundaries where your look for that label, or you will have to _go all-in_ and dive recursively into the whole DOM. From a Component POV that ``<label>`` should be created by the component itself. (either in or outside shadowDOM)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman please see EDIT 1

Comment: You still need ``document.querySelector('[for="disTick"]')`` or something more fancy to find that label.