# Best Practices: autonomous custom elements vs extending native HTML elements (customized built-in elements)

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

A common practice with Custom Elements, at least in Polymer (the most popular Web Components framework), is to define a new custom element. This, IMHO, is not a good practice for **rendered** elements because the element cannot get rendered progressively and has to wait until it is loaded (registered/defined and built up further).

In the contrary, if the element is extended from a native element, it can progressively be enhanced as the regular elements do. The only reason I can think of against this is that new elements look more elegant (`my-element>` vs `<div is=my-element>`).

Am I missing something here? What are the pros and cons of each method?

Update: According to one of the comments, both method are equal in terms of progressive enhancements. However, I have learned a lot more about the differences between the two methods [from here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/509), hence, the question remains valid.

Answer (score 3):

With the current state of the Web Component spec being that [Apple block the agreement on the `is=""` attribute](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/509#issuecomment-233419167) it is discouraged to extend native elements in this way. Actually, Polymer 2.0 moves to composition like

```
<custom-style>
   <style></style>
</custom-style>
```

instead of `<style is="custom-style">`. See [Polymer 2.0 readme](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/2.0-preview/README.md#v1-custom-elements)

Also you may find this [article](https://component.kitchen/blog/posts/writing-a-web-component-that-wraps-a-standard-html-element-might-alleviate-the-need-for-is-syntax) from component.kitchen interesting.

So, for the time being (like, at least until Web Components v2 spec) you'd rather create wrapper elements for best browser support. Your example would change to

```
<my-element>
  <!-- the "extended" native element is wrapped -->
  <div></div>
</my-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

With *Customized Built-In Elements* (extended native HTML element), you [keep the semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34055503/4600982) of the original element.

With *Autonomous Custom Elements* (new ones), you define your own semantics.

Therefore, **the 2 are complementary**. You'll use both syntax in the same project, each one depending of each component requirements.

---

**Use case**: If you want to create a dashbord whith data grids inside that will fetch their content from a REST service:

- Use a new one for the container: `<dash-board>`. That makes no sense to extend a `<div>` element.
- Extend the `table` for the data grids: `<table is="data-grid" data-src="/rest/users">`

---

**Progressive enhancement for Autonomous custom elements**

An unknown autonomous custom element is like a `<span>` element: its default CSS `display` property is `inline`, but you can change that to whatever you want: `inline-block`, `flex`, etc via `<style>` CSS rules, to give it some dimensions/layout, thus ensuring "progressive enhancement".

Also you can insert other elements inside it. They will be displayed as usual.

Comment: How can you get progressive enhancements for Autonomous Custom Elements?

Comment: could you please provide a reference?

Comment: on how autonomous custom element behaves, like a section or span or ... . Is it guaranteed that ACE will display anything at all before it is registered?